# Create macro to find last 8 data points in a column and renaming

Tags: excel, loops

I am trying to create macro that allows me to find the last 8 cells with data and rename them.  I am using this to find the last cell and rename it.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("K65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Name = "BackRho"
```

I need then to go up to the next 8 data points and rename them.  The problem is the column isnt always full so there are blanks between data sometimes.  I think I need to use the Is() empty but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you want:

```
Sub RenameLast8()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SearchColumn As Excel.Range
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range
Dim FirstAddr As String
Dim FoundCells As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set SearchColumn = ws.Range("K:K")
Set FoundCell = SearchColumn.Cells.Find(searchdirection:=XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, what:="*", lookat:=xlPart)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
    FoundCells = FoundCells + 1
    FoundCell.Name = "Name" & FoundCells
End If
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing Or FoundCells = 8
    Set FoundCell = SearchColumn.Cells.FindPrevious(after:=FoundCell)
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        FoundCells = FoundCells + 1
        FoundCell.Name = "Name" & FoundCells
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

If it finds less than eight, it stops.

Change `ws` and `SearchColumn` to suit. I'm not sure of your naming convention, so just used "Name" and the `FoundCells` index.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. And welcome to SO.